# How to get metadata values in javafx?

Tags: java, dictionary, javafx, metadata

I'd like to know why the following code doesn't work. I'm trying to create two `ArrayList<String>` from the values of a file's metadata. In this case, `.mp3` files.

```
private Stage stage;
private List<File> filelist;
private Map<String, Object> map;
private ArrayList<String> artist;
private ArrayList<String> title;    

public void open(){
    FileChooser chooser = new FileChooser();
    filelist = chooser.showOpenMultipleDialog(stage);
    for (int i = 0; i <= filelist.size(); i++){
        try {
            Media media = new Media(filelist.get(i).toURI().toURL().toString());
            map = media.getMetadata();
            title.add(map.get("title").toString());
            artist.add(map.get("artist").toString());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void test(){
    for (int i = 0; i <= filelist.size(); i++){
    System.out.println(filelist.get(i).getName());
    System.out.println(title.get(i));
    System.out.println(artist.get(i));
    }
}
```

When I try to print out the values in artist and title it gives an error

Comment: Can you describe how it doesn't work?

Comment: Did you try debugging the map object or log all its contents?

Comment: Edit your question and add the code where you print those lists and the error message thrown.

Comment: It seems you can only retrieve the data by using a listener. Probably some lazy initialization? At least all the examples I've just found in a 30 second google search don't use the getMetadata() map directly, but instead add a change listener to the map.

Comment: @Roland I realize this, my point is trying to understand why the change listener is required and why the metadata doesn't work like a regular hashmap.

Comment: @Peralta: Because the metadata aren't available if you just simply initialize the Media object with a file. Besides you expect that there's always a "title" and an "artist" metadata, which doesn't have to be the case. What you get is certainly a Nullpointer Exception when calling the toString() method.

Comment: The cause of error is `i <= filelist.size()`. when you try filelist.get(i) the last iteration will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. The correct one should be `i < filelist.size()`.

Comment: Also check out what Uluk Biy said. It'll be the next problem once you get past the nullpointer exception.